# how to use .CER with curl_easy_setopt

Tags: c++, ssl, libcurl

I would like to use .cer file with curl api in C++. I was exploring some options as described in https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html.
here is the code snippet which i tried

```
 curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_URL, "https://test.com/?AppID=DB");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
  struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
  curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

  curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "CER");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "/cacert.cer");
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl1);
```

but here I get error saying
Failed: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not ok

Thanks you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0):

**[`CURLOPT_SSLCERT`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLCERT.html)** sets the **client** certificate, it's supposed to be used in combination with `CURLOPT_SSLKEY`.

To set the **server** (CA) certificate, use **[`CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT.html)** for a single cert or **[`CURLOPT_CAINFO`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO.html)** for a CA bundle.

Though it accepts only `PEM` format.

You can convert DER to PEM using e.g. OpenSSL.

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in cacert.cer -out cacert.pem
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I tried another way and it did work    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/cybercert.cer");